# Not able to get from and to date values from database using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to projectname,activityname,duration,employee names with todate,fromdate,projectid but i am not able to get here my code and scheme

```
select ohrm_project.project_id as ohrmprojectid,ohrm_project.customer_id,ohrm_project.name as ohrm_projectname,ohrm_timesheet.timesheet_id as ohrmtimesheet_id, ohrm_timesheet.employee_id as ohrmtimesheetemployeeid,ohrm_timesheet_item.*, ohrm_project_activity.activity_id as ohrmprojectactivityid, ohrm_project_activity.project_id as ohrmprojectactivityprojectid, ohrm_project_activity.name as activityname,hs_hr_employee.* from ohrm_project,ohrm_timesheet,ohrm_timesheet_item,ohrm_project_activity,hs_hr_employee where ohrm_timesheet_item.project_id=2 and ohrm_timesheet_item.activity_id=ohrm_project_activity.activity_id and ohrm_timesheet_item.employee_id=hs_hr_employee.emp_number and ohrm_timesheet_item.employee_id=hs_hr_employee.emp_number and ohrm_timesheet_item.date between 2016-03-31 and 2016-04-04
```

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zzpy.png)

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qRLW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
SELECT ohrm_project.project_id AS ohrmprojectid,
   ohrm_project.customer_id,
   ohrm_project.name AS ohrm_projectname,
   ohrm_timesheet.timesheet_id AS ohrmtimesheet_id,
   ohrm_timesheet.employee_id AS ohrmtimesheetemployeeid,
   ohrm_timesheet_item.*,
   ohrm_project_activity.activity_id AS ohrmprojectactivityid,
   ohrm_project_activity.project_id AS ohrmprojectactivityprojectid,
   ohrm_project_activity.name AS activityname,
   hs_hr_employee.*
FROM ohrm_project,
     ohrm_timesheet,
     ohrm_timesheet_item,
     ohrm_project_activity,
     hs_hr_employee
WHERE ohrm_timesheet_item.project_id=2
  AND ohrm_timesheet_item.activity_id=ohrm_project_activity.activity_id
  AND ohrm_timesheet_item.employee_id=hs_hr_employee.emp_number
  AND ohrm_timesheet_item.employee_id=hs_hr_employee.emp_number
  AND ohrm_timesheet_item.date BETWEEN '2016-03-31' AND '2016-04-04'
```

Comment: i am getting only 2016-03-31 this data

Comment: The `BETWEEN` operator selects values within a range. Your date range is `'2016-03-31' AND '2016-04-04'`. You have only one date `'2016-03-31'` which meet the condition. (as per your image). So, I think it is okay.

Comment: Other dates in your database table are greater than `'2016-04-04'`. So, it only returns the `'2016-03-31'`.

Answer (score 0):

Dates would be treated as `string`s. Wrap them with `quote`s.

```
ohrm_timesheet_item.date between '2016-03-31' and '2016-04-04'
```